# Why is my "newsletter sign-up" form in my modal dialog window jumping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal window that appears on every pageload on the homepage (which will be modified later), but there's a problem with the way the 'email sign up' form inside of the window loads.

The form will randomly appear at the top of the site for a second, and then jump inside of the modal window to where it's supposed to be, which obviously isn't what I want it to do. I want it to just load inside of the modal like how it's supposed to at all times.

**Here's the settings for the modal:**

```
<!--
To turn off the home page popup box set the following value to false.
-->
{% assign show_home_popup = 'true' %}

<!--
Setting the following value to 'true' will display the popup
only on the user's first visit to the home page on that day.
If the user returns a day later then the popup will display again.
Setting it to 'false' will display the popup every time the user enters
the home page.
-->
{% assign show_on_first_visit_only = 'false' %}

<!--
Paste the "Direct" Photobucket link to the image you want to display in the popup
between the quotes below.
-->

{% assign popup_image = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2oac9b1j2cni7ta/JOINTHEPARTY.png' %}<!--
Set the max image width here if you'd like to make the image smaller
or bigger (i.e. assign image_width = '700').  The default width is 600
pixels, which will take effect if the quotes below are left empty 
(i.e. assign image_width = '' ).
-->
{% assign image_width = '450' %}
```

**Here's the CSS for the modal:**

```
 #homeModal {
    top: 150px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    {% if image_width == blank %}
        max-width: 600px;
    {% else %}
        max-width: {{image_width}}px;
    {% endif %}
    right:0;
    left: 0;
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}



#homeModal img {
    width: 100%;
}
#homeModal iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: -193px;
    left: 25px;
}
 /*#homeModal iframe body,
  #homeModal iframe html
  {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 } */

 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) 
 {
 #homeModal {
 height: 300px;
 width: 350px;
 min-width: 350px;
 }  
 #homeModal iframe {
 left: 1px;
 position: relative;
 top: -163px;
 }
 }
```

**Here's the code/plugin/script for the modal:**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://googledrive.com/host/0B51UCH0yGk6FVkFBakNmUXVuREk/reveal.css">
  <script src="http://googledrive.com/host/0B51UCH0yGk6FVkFBakNmUXVuREk/jquery.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script src="http://googledrive.com/host/0B51UCH0yGk6FVkFBakNmUXVuREk/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#homeModal img').attr('src', '{{popup_image}}');

  {% if show_on_first_visit_only == 'true' %}
  if (!$.cookie("popup")) {
    //trigger your popup message
    $('#homeModal').reveal({
        animation: 'none',                         //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' 
    });       

    //after pop-up show, rewrite the cookie
    $.cookie("popup","false", {expires: 1} ); //not to show again
}
{% else %}
    $('#homeModal').reveal({
        animation: 'none',                         //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' 
    });       
{% endif %}

  });
  </script>
```

**Here's where the problem is:**
http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the loading of your CSS/the order it is being loaded in.

I was able to replicate the issue somewhat by adding the position as 'absolute'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STqnu.png

My suggestion to fix it would be to place the 'position: relative' for the at the very beginning of your CSS file as it at the end. This might fix the issue (somewhat).

This won't actually make it load INSIDE the pop-up, but it 'should' be almost instantaneous.

As how to get it to load properly, why don't you make the entire pop-up an iFrame containing the form.

Comment: Pulled that line of CSS to the bottom and it didn't work. What's weird is that before I added the "top" as "150px" in #homeModal, that's when the jumping started to happen. When the "top" is at "50px" it doesn't jump.

Comment: No, make sure you bring it to the top, not bottom! Unless you wrote it wrong originally

Comment: I just put the "top" for #homeModal to "50px", the way it originally was set, and it doesn't jump. But I want the modal underneath the Moonfall logo, so I can't keep it there.

Answer (score 0):

Your form iframe has this set as its onload function:

```
window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)
```

That's probably whats causing the jump.

Comment: what should I make it then if I want the #homeModal's top set as "150px"?

Comment: Just remove it completely. The code tells your page to scroll to the top as soon as the form loads.

Comment: Removed the onset location and it's still jumping.

Comment: It doesn't jump when the "top" for #homeModal is set to "50px". Anything you could think of?